# Finding the expected value of a continuous random varibale when the commulative distribution is given

Tags: probability, expected-value, density-function

I have this distribution function of a random variable X:

[image]

I wish to find E(X).

I have used derivatives to get the density function, compared it to 1, and found that f(t) = (4/5)*t+(3/5). I then used integral of t*f(t) over the range of 0 to 1, and got 0.56667. According to the answer I got, it's incorrect (maybe the answer is incorrect, not me?). Can you please assist?
Thank you !

Comment: Because the [expectation of any positive variable is the integral of its survival function](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/209193/919), $$\mathbb{E}(X)=\int_0^\infty(1-F(t))dt=\int_0^1(1-Ct-2t^2/5)dt=1-C/2-2/15.$$ Thus, you need only compute $C$.  Could you show us how you found $C$?

Comment: I wasn't planning to use survival functions for this. What I did was simple. I found the density using the derivative of the F, then I compared the density to 1 over the entire range of 0 to 1. This gave me C.

Comment: And?  What do you get when you plug $C$ into the formula?

Comment: I get that C=3/5, and then my integral gives 17/30, using both ways, mine and yours. :-)

Comment: Okay.  But let's notice something: *$C$ is not uniquely defined.*  **Any** value of $C$ between $0$ and $3/5$ is legitimate, because the constraints on it (namely, that $F(t)$ lie between $0$ and $1$ for $0\le t\le 1$ and $F$ is non-decreasing in that same interval) only imply that  $C \le 3/5$ and $C\ge 0$, respectively.  Therefore, *any* expectation between $1-0/2-2/15/=26/30$ and $1-3/10-2/15=17/30$ could be "correct."  The best answer would be to give this entire range of results.

Comment: I am not sure that I understood your last comment.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  This answer is wrong.  It does work out that way to 0.56667.  I made an error with fractions.

Check you integral.  It is not the problem.

Your approach is correct.  Your probability density is correct, but your $$ \int_0^1 t f(t) dt \ne 0.56667 $$.  Rework this integral.

Comment: I re-checked it, with Maple, and it gives me 0.56667.

Comment: Yup.  I mis-calculate.  You are 100% correct.  I work it out to 0.566667 too.  Sorry.